Python aiohttp web server not handling more than one request once
I'm new to python and may be being dumb here, but I can't figure out why my server cant handle more than one connection once.
My sample code:
import time
from aiohttp import web

def testF(request): #I've tried with async def testF also
    print('Called')
    time.sleep(10)
    print('Answered')
    return web.Response(
        content_type="application/json",
        text='',
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app_aio = web.Application()
    app_aio.router.add_post("/test", testF)
    web.run_app(app_aio, host="0.0.0.0", port=5200)

If I run this webserver and call the url multiple times at once it will only start the second run after the first one is returned, why?
Current output:
    Called
    Answered
    Called
    Answered
    Called
    Answered
    Called
    Answered

Expected output:
    Called
    Called
    Called
    Called
    Answered
    Answered
    Answered
    Answered


Aiohttp is an asyncio framework, so you'll need to brush up on how asyncio works to write correct code.
But, to summarise the problem with your code, you need to realise that the event loop can not change context and execute another task unless you see an await or async with/for in your code. These are the only places the code may yield to the event loop and allow it to change context.
Therefore, when your code runs time.sleep(10), the entire application is going to be stuck for 10 seconds waiting for that function to complete. In this simple case, you just want to replace it with await asyncio.sleep(10). This is an async function which will yield to the event loop and schedule the task back into the event loop after 10 seconds, so it can be resumed later.

Also worth noting that when using dev mode (e.g. python -X dev) then asyncio will log warnings if you block the event loop for more than 100ms. When blocking the event loop for long periods like this, asyncio code is not expected to work correctly/reliably.

Here's a good article about the difference between threading and asyncio: https://glyph.twistedmatrix.com/2014/02/unyielding.html
